# My code is not working....Getting Exception or App crashes even if all code is ok

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

**i'm developing EMI calculator app using Tenure and Loan Amount as a input using kotlin, all code is ok but still getting error and code not operating.**

```
    import android.graphics.Color
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.EditText
    import android.widget.TextView
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import kotlin.math.pow
    class EMIPayment : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emipayment)
        title = "EMI Payment"
        supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5")))    
        try {
            val calculateEMI = findViewById<Button>(R.id.calculateEMI)
            val emiView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.EMIView)
            val pe = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.loanAmount)
            val ne = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.tenure)
            val p = pe.toString().toDouble()
            val n = ne.toString().toDouble()
            val r = 0.01717    
            val result = (p*r*(1+r).pow(n))/((1+r).pow(n)-1)
            calculateEMI.setOnClickListener {
                val fin = result*1
                emiView.text = fin.toString()
            }
        } catch (e:NumberFormatException ) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error occurred",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}}}
```

Comment: What error?  Please include the **complete** stacktrace.

Comment: "all code ok" – "but getting error". Apparently the code is not ok; if it was OK, you wouldn't be getting errors.

Comment: @knittl, it's probably a language issue. I think "all code ok" likely means "no compiler errors".

Comment: We need the stack trace of the crash in order to help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert a view to a String and then parse it to a Double:

```
val p = pe.toString().toDouble()
```

This is not possible. What you probably want to do instead is get the text value inside this EditText:

```
val p = pe.getText().toString().toDouble()
```